# SearchQuerySet().filter(content='content') returns results, but they don't show up in search.html

Tags: python, django, search, django-haystack

I can go into my shell and type

```
 sqs = SearchQuerySet().filter(content='content')
 len(sqs)
```

and I get results. I have inspected them and when I type

```
 sqs[0]
 sqs[0].id
 sqs[0].text
```

I get coherent results. However when I use the search form on my website, I get no results.

I don't even define my own SearchView. It is the default one. On the template, I have tried

```
 {% for result in page.object_list %}
 {% for result in object_list %}
 {% for result in page_obj.object_list %}
```

and still don't get any results. And the query did run because I can put stuff inside

```
 {% if query %}
```

so that clearly works. What do I do?

Thank you.

Comment: Post your views.py

Comment: It's the default Haystack view.

Comment: What does `{{ page.object_list|length }}` give you in templates?

Comment: Did you check console for any frontend errors?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov it gives 0.  Console reports no errors.

Comment: Well that means nothing is found. Did you run `update_index ` command? http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/management_commands.html#update-index

Comment: I ran rebuild_index... Why is nothing being found if I can do the sqs search manually in the shell and get results?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by replacing

```
  url(r'^search/', include('haystack.urls')),
```

with

```
 url(r'^search/?$', views.SearchResultsView.as_view(), name='search-view'),
```

and making my own SearchResultsView with nothing special in it

```
 class SearchResultsView(SearchView):
     template_name = 'search/search.html'
     form_class = MySearchForm
     queryset = SearchQuerySet().all()
     paginate_by = 10
     context_object_name = 'object_list'
```

and using

```
  page_obj
```

in the template